# Blur textbox when an item is selected with mouse or enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm having problems trying to resolve the issue with the tab key with an autocomplete field.

The idea is that when a user presses the up or down key, and then tabs to make a selection and move to the next field, what happens is that the tab unexpectedly skips to some other (possible) tabindex.

The whole thing is driving me nuts, here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    var countryTags = ["China", "Colombia", "Cuba"];
    var cityTags = ["China", "Colombia", "Cuba"];
    $("#whatcountry").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(countryTags, request.term);
            response(results.slice(0, 5));
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#whatcity").focus();
        }
    });
    $("#whatcity").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(cityTags, request.term);
            response(results.slice(0, 5));
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Submitme").focus();
        }
    });
    // Hover states on the static widgets
    $("#dialog-link, #icons li").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
        },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
        });
});
```

Please see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tezuttley/VaQk3/3/)! which demonstrates the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `crtfdesc` in your fiddle? And what happens if you remove all `focus()` from your code?

Comment: I have no idea what the crtfdesc, I took the code from somewhere else. If I remove focus, then the code still works with the tab on jsfiddle, but if the mouse is used, I want the focus to shift to the next tab (which does not happen if I remove focus). :(

Comment: Okay I have removed what appears irrelevant code (this includes the crtdesc), but the tab still does not function as expected. I.e using up and down key, and then tabbing the selection, moves the focus to the submit button, instead of the next field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI autocomplete seems to do a good job with setting focus when tab key is used to select an item. Set a special case to handle selection via enter key or click:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    var e = event.originalEvent.originalEvent;
    if (e.which === 1 || e.which === 13) {
        $("#whatever").focus();
    }
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/VaQk3/8/)
[Read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) to improve the code

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried reading the documentation, but my javascript/jquery knowledge is very limited at the moment.